# Firefox - Delete Some Address Auto Fill In

Tags: firefox

You know the site yotube.com right, it is a spam "Youtube" site that says you won an iPad every time you type less a "u". Everytime when I want to go to Youtube.com, when I type "yo", it automatically fill in "yotube.com" and I had to type every character in the address bar to go to youtube, same as "outliik.com". I know I'm lazy, but is there a way to delete the auto fill in history?

Comment: Ohhhh I'm sure you can google this. Plenty of people have this problem..... not it replacing it with youTUBE but uhhh youporn and redtube.

Comment: ... well people had problem with the drop down of the address bar but I can't search for auto-fill

Comment: How do I get porn out of my autofill addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since after my suggestions you were unable to [properly google the answer](http://bit.ly/1duWkOY) I've googled it for you. [The link is here](http://lifehacker.com/5893908/how-to-banish-embarrassing-or-annoying-autocomplete-suggestions-from-your-browser) to summarize highlight the auto-correct and hold shift delete. It goes bye bye.

Comment: Googled lots, and never found this trick.  Then tried the shift-delete.  This makes it disappear from the list, until  you start typing the next time, and it comes right back.  I guess Firefox has broken this fix.  Anyone have any other way to actually totally and completely remove it from the "hidden history" Firefox is evidently keeping?  (other than remove the entire profile, and spend 2 hours getting the 'new and improved' phone-style gui back to useable, again).